# Is it possible to use an animated image for the user picture?

Tags: macos, system-settings, animation

So I dragged my .gif onto he default globe, and it shows the popup allowing me to edit the dimensions of my image. *While I am zooming in/out, it is still animating.* I was overjoyed at this, thinking that if the image animates in the edit panel, then it will animate on the login screen.

Nope.

Even if I re-open the image edit dialog, it *still* shows the animation, but it will not animate no matter what. Is there any way to get this working in the OS, or maybe a program that can do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is currently not possible. You can provide feedback to Apple here:

- https://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html

Comment: Done. Hopefully it's an easy fix, and they actually care to fix it.